# Spring HATEOAS Resource assembler is not instantiated in unit test

Tags: spring, mockito, junit4, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am trying to write a unit test for a REST controller which generates HATEOAS links via Resource assembler class. Everything is OK in production, but with the unit test Resource assembler class is not being injected into the controller.

my resource assembler class is:

```
@Component
public class ModelResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<Model, ModelResource> {
    public ModelResourceAssembler() {
    super(ModelRestController.class, ModelResource.class);

    }

    @Bean 
    public ModelResourceAssembler modelResourceAssembler(){
      return new ModelResourceAssembler();
    }
   @Override
   public ModelResource toResource(Model model) {
   ...
  }
}
```

The controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foo.demo"} )
public class ModelRestController {
    @Autowired
    private ModelPersistenceHandler modelPersistenceHandler;

    @Autowired
    private ModelResourceAssembler modelResourceAssembler;
...
}
```

And the unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes=    {ModelResourceAssembler.class, ModelRestController.class})
public class ModelRestControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private ModelRestController modelRestController;

    @Mock
    private ModelPersistenceHandler modelPersistenceHandler;


    @Before
    public void setup()  {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(modelRestController).build();
   }
   ...
}
```

No matter what I do the ModelResourceAssembler instance is always null. Since the application is Spring Boot it does not have the WebCoonfig classes and autowired WebApplicationContext is always null, so I cannot (and really don't want to since I am running a unit test) instantiate MockMvc via webAppContextSetup

Answer (score 3):

The solution ended up being quite simple: I needed to add one line to my test:

```
  @Spy
   private ModelResourceAssembler modelResourceAssembler;
```

And the bean was instantiated and properly wired

Answer (score 1):

In your example you use `@InjectMocks` but don't declare a mock for `ModelResourceAssembler`. You don't get an instance out of nowhere.

You use the `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`. It has no idea of Spring beans. For testing Spring applications you rather want to use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`.

Comment: The problem with using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner is that in instantiates all the beans before Mockito injects the mocks. In my case the real modelPersistenceHandler and not its mock is instantiated and the test fails immediately because modelPersistenceHandler attempt to talk to the database.

Comment: @MrkK Not if you replace it with a mock **bean(!)**. Anyway, the current problem is explained in the first paragraph. The second one is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If i may suggest, if you use constructor injection for your controller then you can just mock the dependency and not need spring junit test runner stuff.